# Invertible and (local) inverse of multivariable function

Tags: multivariable-calculus

> **Question:**
> $$f: \mathbb{R}^{2} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^{2} $$
> defined by: $f(x,y) = (x^{2} - y^{2}, xy)$

Determine the derivative of the local inverse of f in point (1,1)

**My attempt:**
The jacobian is:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
2x & 2y \\
y & x 
\end{pmatrix}
$$

$$J(1,1):
\begin{pmatrix}
2 & -2 \\
1 & 1
\end{pmatrix}
$$

The inverse of this matrix $J(1,1)^{-1}$:
$$
\begin{pmatrix}
\frac{1}{4} & \frac{1}{2} \\ 
\frac{-1}{4} & \frac{1}{2}
\end{pmatrix}
$$

And I think this should be the derivative of the local inverse in (1,1)
Is this correct?